# apply function to some rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, apply, rows

I want to do several changes to some rows in a pandas dataframe. The rows to change are selected based on the contents of some other columns. The dataset is large, and I have not managed to find a solution which is not very slow.

The following toy code illustrates the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def change1(s):

    if s['a'] == 1:
        s[['b', 'c']] = s[['c', 'b']].values
    
    return s

def change2(s):

    s[['b', 'c']] = s[['c', 'b']].values
    
    return s


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
print('original:')
print(df)

df = df.apply(change1, axis = 1)
print('change1:')
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})
df.loc[df['a']==1,:] = df.loc[df['a']==1,:].apply(change2, axis=1)
print('change2:')
print(df)
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the second strategy (change2) not work, while the first one does?
2. What would be a more correct, and faster, way to do this?

Comment: This code is very confusing. Try show us some example data, explain what you want to do, and then show an example of the transformed data you'd like to see after those transformations are made to the original data

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
df.loc[df['a']==1, ['b','c']] = df.loc[df['a']==1,['c','b']].values
```

`change2` doesn't work because `df.loc[df['a']==1,:]` is a slice of df based on a `df['a']==1` returned as a view, so when you pull `['b','c']` from this slice, you get a copy, so assignment will have no effect on the original df.